# How can I programmatically open the permission screen for a specific app on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a question regarding the new Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) release.

Is it possible to display the "App Permissions" screen for a specific app via an Intent or something similar?

[image: Android M Permission Screen]

It is possible to display the app's "App Info" screen in Settings with the following code:

```java
startActivity(
    new Intent(
        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)
    )
);
```

Is there an analogous solution for directly opening the app's "App Permissions" screen?

I already did some research on this but I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Comment: check this [Open Application Settings Screen Android](http://tips.androidgig.com/open-application-settings-screen-android/#.XNuKA4g1WK0.stackoverflow)

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973175/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-application-settings/71837394#71837394

Answer (score 581):

According to the official Marshmallow permissions video (at the [4m 43s mark](https://youtu.be/iZqDdvhTZj0?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-YUddw59dYq61o3ynn3A4X&t=283)), you must open the application Settings page instead (from there it is one click to the Permissions page).

To open the settings page, you would do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is redirecting to general details of Application screen.
How can go to specifically App Permissions screen.
I don't want that remaining one click too,

Comment: @MilindMevada -  you cannot do that at the moment.

Comment: could you send data from the settings activity to your activity using intents, in "realtime"? the issue im facing is handling this data in your activity **once** it got sent from the settings.

Comment: This works when debugging the app, but crashes with no real reason after signing the APK. Nothing obvious in the logcat either.

Comment: Use `context.packageName` instead of `getPackageName()`.

Answer (score 211):

***This is not possible.*** I tried to do so, too. I could figure out the package name and the activity which will be started. But in the end you will get a security exception because of a missing permission you can't declare.

---

Regarding the other answer I also recommend to open the App settings screen. I do this with the following code:

```java
public static void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(final Activity context) {
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
    final Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

As I don't want to have this in my history stack I remove it using intent flags.

Kotlin Version:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
with(intent) {
   data = Uri.fromParts("package", requireContext().packageName, null)
   addCategory(CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
   addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
   addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
   addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
}

startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: I experienced the same and thought there might be a workaround / another solution for this... :-/

Comment: Nope, unfortunately its not possible by design. For more information check out this discussion on Google+: https://goo.gl/Wqjjff

Comment: Is it possible to achieve if the user gave the app root-access ?  If so, how? What about the global permissions screen? The one that lists all of the permissions, of all apps?

Comment: It definetley has to be possible because that is exactly what whatsapp is doing. if you install whatsapp on android 6.0 device at first start you get a dialog where you can open the permissions settings.

Comment: @Mulgard Just tried this and I get a dialog generated by Whatsapp asking whether it can ask you for permissions, followed by the native Android permission requests. No automtic opening of permission settings.

Comment: @Mulgard Whatsapp must be using targetSdk="23". This allows the app to to prompt the user to enable the permission. If your target SDK < 23, being able to show the user the app permissions screen is useful, however seems like we can only show the general app settings screen.

Comment: The Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY may sometimes cause a problemous situation on tablets when a pop-up is shown within the settings screen it will close the settings screen. Simply removing that flag will solve this issue.

Comment: How to go one level lower? The user is redirected to Application Info in the Settings section, but they still have to press on the Permission section. That is a lot to ask of the user (they aren't technical nor reliable). How can I take them all the way to the Permission section?

Comment: @Thomas R. What is the activity that you said must be started to do so but that was generating the security exception because of the missing permission that can't be declared? I'm curious about that.

Comment: You can show a Toast at the same time instructing the user to go into "Permission" (good idea to localize this message even if rest of your app is not available in the language of the user)

Comment: @vgergo How to get the localized version of a settings name ? (same string as the one used in the settings) Is it possible ?

Comment: Pretty old question. Is it still not possible in 2024?

Answer (score 118):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Description**

**`Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`**
  
*Opens Details setting page for App. From here user have to manually assign desired permission.*

**`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`**
  
***Optional***. If set then opens Settings Screen(Activity) as new activity. Otherwise, it will be opened in currently running activity.

**`Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)`**
  
*Prepares or creates URI, whereas, getPackageName() - returns name of your application package.*

**`intent.setData(uri)`**
  
***Don't forget to set this***. Otherwise, you will get `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`. *Because you have set your intent as* `Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` *and android expects some name to search.*

Comment: This is literally what the top-voted answer is. Why duplicate this and not extend the original answer?!

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: Note that FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag so as not to embed the settings application into your app task.

Answer (score 48):

If you want to write less code in `Kotlin` you can do this:

```
fun Context.openAppSystemSettings() {
    startActivity(Intent().apply {
        action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
        data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
    })
}
```

Based on [Martin Konecny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32983128/2736039) answer

Comment: nice use of Kotin extensions

Comment: Here's a shorter version:
`fun Context.openAppSystemSettings() = startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)))`

Comment: you have leave a not that it is just app details settings but you have to tap on permissions button then anyway to open permissions screen

Answer (score 43):

Instead, you can open a particular app's general settings with one line:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));
```

Comment: You may want to use getActivity().getPackageName() to get the package name depending on how your build is configured.

Answer (score 30):

Kotlin style.

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).apply {
    data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
})
```

Answer (score 21):

Starting with Android 11, you can directly bring up the app-specific settings page for the **location permission only** using code like this: `requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION), PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)`

However, the above will only work one time.  If the user denies the permission or even accidentally dismisses the screen, the app can never trigger this to come up again.

Other than the above, the answer remains the same as prior to Android 11 -- the best you can do is bring up the app-specific settings page and ask the user to drill down two levels manually to enable the proper permission.

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
intent.data = uri
// This will take the user to a page where they have to click twice to drill down to grant the permission
startActivity(intent)
```

See my related question here: [Android 11 users can’t grant background location permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64246883/android-11-users-can-t-grant-background-location-permission)

Comment: this is answer if off-topic, question has nothing to do with Location Background permission!

Answer (score 18):

It is not possible to programmatically open the permission screen. Instead, we can open the app settings screen.

**Code**

```java
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
startActivity(i);
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: He is asking for Permission page

Answer (score 8):

**Xamarin Forms Android:**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
public void OpenSettings()
//---------------------------------------------------------
{
    var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings,
        Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Forms.Context.PackageName));
    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin

```
    /*
*
* To open app notification permission screen instead of setting
* */
fun Context.openAppNotificationSettings() {
    val intent = Intent().apply {
        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
                action = Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
                putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, packageName)
            }
            else -> {
                action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                data = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName)
            }
        }
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Above one is tested and working code, hope it will help.

Comment: Yes it works, but I needed to change ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS to ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS, because you can't do anything in ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS

Answer (score 5):

May be this will help you

```
private void openSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51251354/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

If we are talking about [Flyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meizu#Flyme) (Meizu) **only**, it has its own security app with permissions.

To open it, use the following intent:

```
public static void openFlymeSecurityApp(Activity context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.meizu.safe.security.SHOW_APPSEC");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra("packageName", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Of course, *BuildConfig* is your app's *BuildConfig*.

Answer (score 0):

> Open the permission screen for a specific app

```
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                //Permission is not granted yet. Ask for permission.
                val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                alertDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.file_permission))
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("सेटिंग") { _, _ ->
                    val intent = Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                        Uri.fromParts("package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null)
                    )
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("हाँ") { _, _ ->
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        context as Activity, arrayOf(
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        ), 1
                    )
                }
                alertDialog.show()
            } else {}
```

Answer (score -1):

**It is not possible** to pragmatically get the permission...
but I’ll suggest you to put that line of code in try{} catch{} which make your app unfortunately stop...

And in the catch body, make a dialog box which will navigate the user to a small tutorial to enable the draw over other apps' permissions...
then on the <kbd>Yes</kbd> button click add this code...

```
Intent callSettingIntent= new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
startActivity(callSettingIntent);
```

This intent is to **directly open the list of draw over other apps** to manage permissions and then from here it is one click to the draw over other apps' permissions.

I know this is *not* the answer you're looking for... but I’m doing this in my apps...

Answer (score -1):

According to Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setComponent(android.content.ComponentName))

**Try This**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(appDetails.packageName,"com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.ManagePermissionsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63615868/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).