# How to open app permission Settings in MIUI devices programmatically?

Tags: android, permissions, settings

I want to open the screen like this: **Settings -> Apps -> Select an app -> Open App permissions screen**.

Currently I used this code. It lets me open the **AppInfo** screen. But I don't know how to select the App permissions screen.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", APP_PACKAGE_NAME, null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Some devices running MIUI have the app permissions screen.

Comment: here is solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android

Comment: @power That is not what the question is. MIUI uses a different shell for permissions.

Comment: @TOP did you find a solution?

Comment: Working Soulution for all MIUI versions on https://stackoverflow.com/a/45206931/5140377

Answer (score 4):

Just add this code and call applyMiuiPermission() method

```
private static final String TAG = "MiuiUtils";

public static void applyMiuiPermission(Context context) {
    int versionCode = getMiuiVersion();
    if (versionCode == 5) {
        goToMiuiPermissionActivity_V5(context);
    } else if (versionCode == 6) {
        goToMiuiPermissionActivity_V6(context);
    } else if (versionCode == 7) {
        goToMiuiPermissionActivity_V7(context);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "this is a special MIUI rom version, its version code " + versionCode);
    }
}


public static int getMiuiVersion() {
    String version = RomUtils.getSystemProperty("ro.miui.ui.version.name");
    if (version != null) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(version.substring(1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "get miui version code error, version : " + version);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void goToMiuiPermissionActivity_V5(Context context) {
    Intent intent = null;
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package" , packageName, null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (isIntentAvailable(intent, context)) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "intent is not available!");
    }
}


public static void goToMiuiPermissionActivity_V6(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
    intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
    intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", context.getPackageName());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    if (isIntentAvailable(intent, context)) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Intent is not available!");
    }
}


public static void goToMiuiPermissionActivity_V7(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
    intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
    intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", context.getPackageName());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    if (isIntentAvailable(intent, context)) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Intent is not available!");
    }
}
```

RomUtils.Java

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class RomUtils {
    private static final String TAG = "RomUtils";

    public static boolean checkIsMiuiRom() {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(getSystemProperty("ro.miui.ui.version.name"));
    }
    public static String getSystemProperty(String propName) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop " + propName);
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()), 1024);
            line = input.readLine();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to read sysprop " + propName, ex);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception while closing InputStream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return line;
    }

    public static boolean checkIsMeizuRom() {
        return Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Meizu");
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide that RomUtils function.

Comment: my answer is edited and check RomUtils class is there

Comment: thanks, the thing is now miui has version 9, is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: as per my knowledge version 9 is above marshmallow and you can check the permissions and ask the permissions common way.If you not get ask me once i will try to explain in detail because my English is poor.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", "app_package_name");
```

Comment: It opens app info page only in Android 5.1 on MIUI 8

Comment: how to window pop permissions add MIUI 6 up version  and my project not display custom call screen android

Answer (score 1):

Solution got form [here](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/start-in-background-xiaomi-phone.135792/).

This code will open application permissions settings

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
localIntent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
localIntent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
startActivity(localIntent);
```

Comment: this code working fine in all android version. Thanks @Ton