# How to open Draw Overlay permission popup in MIUI?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-popupwindow

[image]

I want to open this permission popup in **MIUI**. I have tried this code, but this will not open permission manager popup for a particular app.

```
public static Intent toPermissionManager(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
    String version = getVersionName();
    if (MIUI_V5.equals(version)) {
        PackageInfo pInfo;
        try {
            pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
            return null;
        }
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.miui.securitycenter.permission.AppPermissionsEditor");
        intent.putExtra("extra_package_uid", pInfo.applicationInfo.uid);
    } else { // MIUI_V6 and above
        final String PKG_SECURITY_CENTER = "com.miui.securitycenter";
        try {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PKG_SECURITY_CENTER, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
            return null;
        }
        intent.setClassName(PKG_SECURITY_CENTER, "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
        intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", packageName);
    }
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Please add a follow up here if you have found a solution.

Comment: sorry still i have no solution

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: still i have no solution

Comment: have find solution?

Comment: no i can't find solution for this issue

Comment: @OmerKarakose , @ Mohammad Rizky Kurniawan,@ SanVed  I have uploaded answer for this please check it .Hope It will solve your problem

Answer (score 18):

Call This method directly `onDisplayPopupPermission()` where you want to use this `permission`.

To check permission is `granted` or `not` I have added one more answer above, please check.

```
private void onDisplayPopupPermission() {
    if (!isMIUI()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        // MIUI 8
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
        localIntent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
        localIntent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
        startActivity(localIntent);
        return;
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
    try {
        // MIUI 5/6/7
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
        localIntent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
        localIntent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
        startActivity(localIntent);
        return;
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
    // Otherwise jump to application details
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
 }


private static boolean isMIUI() {
    String device = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if (device.equals("Xiaomi")) {
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getRootDirectory(), "build.prop")));
            return prop.getProperty("ro.miui.ui.version.code", null) != null
                    || prop.getProperty("ro.miui.ui.version.name", null) != null
                    || prop.getProperty("ro.miui.internal.storage", null) != null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

> It will redirect to display popup window permission screen you can manually change it to on off

Comment: Is there a way to know if the user has selected Accept or Deny?

Comment: @SrikarReddy do you found the solution for knowing if accept or deny was selected?

Comment: @SrikarReddy It's late to update but I have uploaded the answer to check permission `granted` or `Not` you can try for it.

Comment: @Gautam You can try for the solution that i have uploaded

Comment: How did you find this solution?

Comment: On Android O, exception is thrown: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/build.prop (Permission denied)

Comment: @chengsam use getSystemProperty(String propName) from [https://stackoverflow.com/q/59974951/4232793](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59974951/4232793)

Comment: its not working in MIUI 11

Answer (score 6):

This below code is working for me. You need these two class **MIUIUtils.java** and **BuildProperties.java**

MIUIUtils.java

```
public class MIUIUtils {
    private static final String MIUI_V5 = "V5";
    private static final String MIUI_V6 = "V6";

    private static final String KEY_MIUI_VERSION_CODE = "ro.miui.ui.version.code";
    private static final String KEY_MIUI_VERSION_NAME = "ro.miui.ui.version.name";
    private static final String KEY_MIUI_INTERNAL_STORAGE = "ro.miui.internal.storage";

    public static boolean isMIUI() {
        try {
            final BuildProperties prop = BuildProperties.newInstance();
            return prop.getProperty(KEY_MIUI_VERSION_CODE, null) != null
                || prop.getProperty(KEY_MIUI_VERSION_NAME, null) != null
                || prop.getProperty(KEY_MIUI_INTERNAL_STORAGE, null) != null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMIUIV5() {
        return getVersionName().equals(MIUI_V5);
    }

    public static boolean isMIUIV6() {
        return getVersionName().equals(MIUI_V6);
    }

    public static String getVersionName() {
        try {
            final BuildProperties prop = BuildProperties.newInstance();
            return prop.getProperty(KEY_MIUI_VERSION_NAME);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static boolean isFloatWindowOptionAllowed(Context context) {
        AppOpsManager manager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        Class localClass = manager.getClass();
        Class[] arrayOfClass = new Class[3];
        arrayOfClass[0] = Integer.TYPE;
        arrayOfClass[1] = Integer.TYPE;
        arrayOfClass[2] = String.class;
        try {
            Method method = localClass.getMethod("checkOp", arrayOfClass);
            if (method == null) {
                return false;
            }
            Object[] arrayOfObjects = new Object[3];
            arrayOfObjects[0] = Integer.valueOf(24);
            arrayOfObjects[1] = Integer.valueOf(Binder.getCallingUid());
            arrayOfObjects[2] = context.getPackageName();
            int m = ((Integer) method.invoke((Object) manager, arrayOfObjects)).intValue();
            return m == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Intent toPermissionManager(Context context, String packageName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
        String version = getVersionName();
        if (MIUI_V5.equals(version)) {
            PackageInfo pInfo;
            try {
                pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
                return null;
            }
            intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.miui.securitycenter.permission.AppPermissionsEditor");
            intent.putExtra("extra_package_uid", pInfo.applicationInfo.uid);
        } else { // MIUI_V6 and above
            final String PKG_SECURITY_CENTER = "com.miui.securitycenter";
            try {
           context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PKG_SECURITY_CENTER, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
                return null;
            }
            intent.setClassName(PKG_SECURITY_CENTER, "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
            intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", packageName);
        }
        return intent;
    }


    public static Intent toFloatWindowPermission(Context context, String packageName) {
        Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName);
        Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, packageUri);
        detailsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        if (isMIUIV5()) {
            return detailsIntent;
        } else {
            Intent permIntent = toPermissionManager(context, packageName);
            return permIntent == null ? detailsIntent : permIntent;
        }
    }
}
```

BuildProperties.java

```
public class BuildProperties {

    private final Properties properties;

    private BuildProperties() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getRootDirectory(), "build.prop"));
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        in.close();
    }

    public static BuildProperties newInstance() throws IOException {
        return new BuildProperties();
    }

    public boolean containsKey(final Object key) {
        return properties.containsKey(key);
    }

    public boolean containsValue(final Object value) {
        return properties.containsValue(value);
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet() {
        return properties.entrySet();
    }

    public String getProperty(final String name) {
        return properties.getProperty(name);
    }

    public String getProperty(final String name, final String defaultValue) {
        return properties.getProperty(name, defaultValue);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return properties.isEmpty();
    }

    public Enumeration<Object> keys() {
        return properties.keys();
    }

    public Set<Object> keySet() {
        return properties.keySet();
    }

    public int size() {
        return properties.size();
    }

    public Collection<Object> values() {
        return properties.values();
    }
}
```

Call in your code like this:

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && MIUIUtils.isMIUI() && !MIUIUtils.isFloatWindowOptionAllowed(context)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "MIUI DEVICE: Screen Overlay Not allowed");
            startActivityForResult(MIUIUtils.toFloatWindowPermission(context, getPackageName()), REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "SDK_INT > 23: Screen Overlay Not allowed");
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                            "android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION", 
                            Uri.parse("package:" +getPackageName()))
                    , REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION
            );
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "SKK_INT < 19 or Have overlay permission");

        }
```

Comment: It opens only app info page in MIUI8 on Android 5.1

Comment: On Android O, exception is thrown: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/build.prop (Permission denied)

Answer (score 1):

To check if `Display popup window` permission is Granted or not, using `onDisplayPopupPermission()` this method is from my above answer.

I am using `canDrawOverlayViews` and `reflection` to check `permission is granted` or not this may be `removed/changed in the latest releases`.

> This solution I have tried up to `MIUI8` it's working, not sure about
>   the latest updates. Please give an update on the comment so others can have updates.

**1.Step**

```
if (!canDrawOverlayViews() && isXiaomi()) {
        //permission not granted
        Log.e("canDrawOverlayViews", "-No-");
       onDisplayPopupPermission(); 
        //write above answered permission code for MIUI here
    }else {

    }
```

**2.Step**
Check if permission granted or not

```
public boolean canDrawOverlayViews() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        return true;
    }
    Context con = this;
    try {
        return Settings.canDrawOverlays(con);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        return canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(con);
    }
}

public static boolean isXiaomi() {
    return "xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER);
}
```

**canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection()** I have found this solution here [here translate this page](https://mlog.club/article/209479)

```
public static boolean canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(Context context) {

try {

    AppOpsManager manager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    Class clazz = AppOpsManager.class;
    Method dispatchMethod = clazz.getMethod("checkOp", new Class[] { int.class, int.class, String.class });
    //AppOpsManager.OP_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW = 24
    int mode = (Integer) dispatchMethod.invoke(manager, new Object[] { 24, Binder.getCallingUid(), context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() });

    return AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED == mode;

} catch (Exception e) {  return false;  }
```

}

Comment: What is canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection() method?

Comment: @javaDroid please check to update Its been long time that I have worked on it please make sure its working and update on it

Comment: I have tried this solution and it does not work for MIUI 10 and above, not tried on < 10

Comment: @GastónSaillén This solution I have tried up to `MIUI8` it's working, for MIUI `> 8` Please update your answer

Comment: I checked, but `Settings.canDrawOverlays(con);` in `canDrawOverlayViews()` method always return false.

Comment: has anyone found the solution to this issue?