# Unable to read messages programmatically from Xiaomi phones

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions, telephonymanager, xiaomi

I am using `EasyPermission` to taking `permissions` from user.

```
@AfterPermissionGranted(PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS)
private void readSMS() {
    String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.READ_SMS};
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
        initSMS();
    } else {
        // Do not have permissions, request them now
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.send_sms_rationale),
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    }
}
```

In my `initSMS()`  I had tried to read messages from Android devices. Its worked fine for all devices except `Xiaomi` devices. I used `TelephonyProvider` class to read messages.

```
private void initSMS() {
    TelephonyProvider provider = new TelephonyProvider(this);
    List<Sms> sms = provider.getSms(TelephonyProvider.Filter.INBOX).getList();
    for(int i = 0; i <= sms.size() - 1; i++) {
        Log.d("Address",sms.get(i).address);
        Log.d("Sms",sms.get(i).body);
        Log.d("ReceivedDate",""+sms.get(i).receivedDate));
        Log.d("State",""+sms.get(i).status);
        Log.d("person",""+sms.get(i).person);
    }
}
```

Is their any way to read all messages from `Xiaomi` devices?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061459/3117966) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38309200/3117966)

Comment: Thanks..@Nilu and @Nisarg these links useful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this will work for you. firstly you have to call function isMIUI() for checking miui mobile and then call this above function. this function will redirect to setting for taking service sms permission.

```
private void onDisplayPopupPermission() {

        try {
            // MIUI 8
            Intent localIntent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
            localIntent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
            localIntent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
            localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(localIntent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                // MIUI 5/6/7
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
                localIntent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
                localIntent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
                localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(localIntent);


            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // Otherwise jump to application details
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. this code is working for me. now i am getting permission and sms for miui phone.

Comment: Thanks! You saved a day!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can we check if permission is given or not?

Comment: @Sanju  Have you got how to check whether permission is given or not?