# overlay permissions in xiaomi devices

Tags: android, permissions, overlay, xiaomi

Is there any way to check and get the following permission in Xiaomi devices?

-Display pop-up windows while running in the background (from the other permissions section in app settings).

Currently tried solution proposed in this

[How to open Draw Overlay permission popup in MIUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123349/how-to-open-draw-overlay-permission-popup-in-miui/45206931#)

but it only checks Display pop-up window permission.