# Android M - Permission settings redirect (INTENT ACTION)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there a way to redirect a user to the settings of an application or better to the permissions of a specific application? as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to redirect a user to the settings of an application

[Use `ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).

> or better to the permissions of a specific application?

I do not think that there is a way to drive to that specific screen.

Comment: I'm getting a crash:  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS }

Comment: @FeleMed: As the documentation states, "In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this." Beyond that, you need to put a `Uri` on the `Intent`, one with a `package` scheme that points to your app. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32983128/115145.

Comment: ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS worked, thanks. On the second question, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f17qe9vZ8RM at around 27:30 the speaker said that if your permissions haven't been denied before you can intent directly to the app permissions, can't find the documentation though.

Comment: @FeleMed: I don't see anything undocumented in [the current Settings app's manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml) that fits the bill, but, then again, there are a million references to "permission" in there... :-)

Answer (score 12):

There is no intent to go directly to permissions page.

However, there is an intent by which you can redirect your user to your Application's detailed settings page.
[ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)

Here is the code snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",activity.getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: the context it is undefined so it is the activity what do I need to write there for both of them ?
I tried `getApplicationContext().startActivity` but it is throwing me error.

Comment: This is creating runtime exception android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. so we need to set the flag for the intent ```intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);```