# How to open application permission window in app settings programmatically

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-settings

I'm working on new permission model (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) and I wonder is there a way to open the application's permission window programmatically?

[image: app permissions]

not only application details

[image: app settings]

I managed to open the second screen using something like this

```
private void goToSettings() {
    Intent myAppSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    myAppSettings.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    myAppSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(myAppSettings);
}
```

But I have no idea how to open the first one.

Your help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**This is not possible.** You can open the App settings screen but not the permissions setting screen.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android) for more explanations.

Here I am sharing code to open application setting screen,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

For more you can refer [Open Application Settings Screen Android](http://tips.androidgig.com/open-application-settings-screen-android/#.XNuKA4g1WK0.stackoverflow)

Comment: Sad to hear that. I was hoping there is a way. Thank you for pointing the main question on SO. (I was searching for answear but missed this one) Thank you again.

Comment: How did u solved it ?  Karol Żygłowicz

Comment: Is there a way to open any other application setting from a particular application ?

Comment: It works for me, thanks!!

Comment: if anyone was wondering `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`

Comment: you answer is just only can go in the app info, not to permission window.

Comment: @ShweLiam I hope you have read first line of my answer.