# Android M : How to open Permission Dialog even if user selects Never Ask Again ?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

If not what is the workaround to prompt user to setting page or any other solution ?

Comment: uninstall and install again, It will work for me.

Comment: don't check the boolean value for `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't open the request permission dialog if user selects Never Ask Again.
But you can show the information to user.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // do your work here
                } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go to Settings and Grant the permission to use this feature.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // User selected the Never Ask Again Option
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Settings Screen:**
To open the settings screen you can use the below intent.

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

For more info you can check the thread on [How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)

Comment: Can I redirect user to Settings page??

Comment: Thanks a lot Deepak

Comment: Thanks a lot @DeepakGoyal... You saved my day