# How to handle Never ask again checkbox in Android M

Tags: android

We have upgraded our application to Android M and now it asks for user access before using any of the permissions in dangerous permission set introduced in Android M.

A pop up will be shown to user asking for access. if user chooses to deny access as expected we disallow user from user from using feature , but again request user for access.

While the user access pop up shown  if user checks never ask again checkbox and chooses to deny access... no pop up for user access will be shown further. But since access to permission is critical so some how we want to let user know that a critical permission access is missing.

How to handle this situation.

Thanks

Comment: check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847122/android-m-how-to-open-permission-dialog-even-if-user-selects-never-ask-again/39847233#39847233

Comment: Sure deepak.. Thanks for commenting ... I will check your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719047/android-m-check-runtime-permission-how-to-determine-if-the-user-checked-nev

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609834/how-to-forget-the-never-ask-again-choice-in-android-m-runtime-permission-dialo

Comment: Thanks Deepak it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` call. This will check for you if you already asked for permission and if it was rejected. So you can easily find out if it is a good idea to ask the user or not.

If the user clicked on ask never again you can send your user to your app settings with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getContext().getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
```