# Best way to handle runtime permission in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

i have an old project with target sdk 21, now i have to put run time permission in that so can anyone suggest me any best and simple way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Create two variables like

```
 private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
 String mPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
```

after create method like this

```
 private void getPermission() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 23) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(mPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{mPermission,
                    },
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            /* your code if permission already access 
        }
    }
}
```

After override onRequestPermissionsResult method like this

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Log.e("Req Code", "" + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            methodRedirect();
        }
        else{
            this.getPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

In this way even user deny permission, it will show again.

You can manage multiple permission like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle permission on Splash Screen or First Screen.

if multiple permission then handle all one time.

if user denied any permission then it show message some permission required.

hope it will help you.

Here is example how to handle multiple permission.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


 if(checkAndRequestPermissions()){
     //all permission granted
 }else{
     //require all permission.
 }

}


private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int camerapermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int phonestate = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    int location = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int recordaudio = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (camerapermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if (phonestate != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
    if (location != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (recordaudio != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    }

    if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}



 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

            perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

            // Fill with actual results from user
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for both permissions
                if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        ) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "camera & location services permission granted");

                    // here you can do your logic all Permission Success Call
                        moveToNxtScreen();

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        showDialogOK("Some Permissions are required for Open Camera",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        switch (which) {
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                break;
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        explain("You need to give some mandatory permissions to continue. Do you want to go to app settings?");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show();
}

private void explain(String msg) {
    final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    Utils.startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(LoginActivity.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    dialog.create().dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanx Sachin, but what if user deny permission after splash screen from settings? so i have keep check everywhere.

Comment: Then you need to check every time permission is granted or not. if permission denied simpley show toast permission required and open permission setting screen . Check this how to open Permission Screen http://stackoverflow.com/a/32983128/3416642