# Open Camera Settings directly from code

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that reads the metadata of images from a device.
One of the conditions is to have activated the geolocation for the photos of your camera to retrieve latitude/longitude from images.
Is it possible to send user (via Intent or something else) to the Camera settings/preferences directly?

I know it's possible to send user to general settings

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I'm looking for a way to send it directly to the camera settings.

Comment: Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html to know how to handle camera operations

Comment: What do you mean exactly by camera settings? You mean the settings of a particular camera application? For in the system settings there is no special Camera settings category.

Comment: @Adinia I mean the "standard" Camera application of the device. In system settings usually exists a list of your apps and one of them is the Camera application. There you can configure different permissions such as enable the location of the photos

Comment: Well, I was afraid of that; are you aware that different devices have different camera apps, that ask for a different set of permissions, and Location might not be one of them? Also, some users, like me, might have more than one camera app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to send user (via Intent or something else) to the Camera settings/preferences directly?

No.

> I mean the "standard" Camera application of the device. In system settings usually exists a list of your apps and one of them is the Camera application.

No. There are ~2 billion Android devices, comprising thousands of device models. Those ship with hundreds of pre-installed camera apps, let alone the additional camera apps that users might install.

And, of note:

- None of those camera apps have to have any sort of settings/preferences screen
- None of those camera apps have to offer geolocation