# How do I invoke the phone settings from flutter dart application?

Tags: flutter

Something similar to [How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android) but for flutter dart.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-readme-tab-) package

Open app settings

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

bool isOpened = await PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
```

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler_platform_interface/lib/src/permission_handler_platform_interface.dart
I check the source code of that package and found this.

Future<bool> openAppSettings() {
    throw UnimplementedError('openAppSettings() has not been implemented.');
  }

Answer (score 8):

You can use openAppSettings() method.

```
 var status = await Permission.camera.status;
 if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
              await openAppSettings();
            }
```

Comment: I didn't even know this exists. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Use [android_intent](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent) plugin and put this code:

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS",
  package: "your_app_package_name",
  data: "package:your_app_package_name",
);
intent.launch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [platform plugins](https://flutter.io/platform-plugins/) to call native APIs. In this case, you should use the [Android intent](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/android_intent) plugin.