# Open app permission with IntentLauncherAndroid

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to open the app's [permission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9K0v.png), but the [doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher.html) does not provide any details on how to specify the `data` param to achieve this.

What should I pass to `data` to accomplish this?

EDIT: please stop marking this as duplicate. This is a React Native Expo app as tagged below. Android solutions will require detaching from Expo...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)

Comment: @Eselfar this is a React Native app using the Expo library, so the solution is pure javascript.

Comment: What happen if you do: `IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivityAsync(
 IntentLauncherAndroid.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
);` which is a mix of both the example in the documentation you've linked and the Java solution above

Comment: @Eselfar it didn't work...I need to set the `data` parameter as well but there's no `Uri` in React Native.

Comment: HAve a look at this https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/linking.html

Comment: @Eselfar how would that help me to open the permission screen on Android?

Comment: You were saying there is no Uri in React Native. If you follow the link above, they explain how to pass  data. So I thought it could help you to find a solution