# Re-request accepted permission on Android within app?

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to be a good citizen and allow the user to change their location permission preference within the app after their original choice.  The problem is that using this code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
       {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, RESULT_APP_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
```

only works if the user has not allowed the permission.  In other words, if they have allowed the FINE_LOCATION permission then no dialog shows and they cannot downgrade their choice to deny location permission without going to the system menu.  Is it possible to re-request this location permission after it has been accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You might look into just navigating them to the settings page for your app's permissions. Here's a link to a question that would answer how to navigate there:

[How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)

Comment: Thanks.  I've ended up doing something similiar.  But I'm unhappy with the experience of a user being presented with one dialog for accepting initial permissions and then being punted to an app setting's page where they have to click through to permissions.

Comment: True, that would be frustrating. I'm sure you could create an activity that emulates the behavior of that settings page, where it shows the list of permissions with a toggle next to each one.