# how to remove the third permission option

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I've already googled this question but haven't found anything yet, so I need your help. How to remove the third option of permission to the memory, because if the user accidentally clicks on it, it will be necessary to go to the settings and allow the permission to the program manually, and since in general 30-40% of users are able to do this, only one will have to reinstall the program .

[image]

[image]

Comment: rebuild the OS yourself, flash your device and you can remove the option :-)

Comment: I know it is possible to do so, this picture proves it

Comment: That doesn't prove that at all. It just proves it isn't there on _some_ Android versions. That is an OS feature. You'll need to handle the situation if the user denies permission. You can navigate the user directly to your app's permissions.

Comment: This is not possible as it is a System's permission dialog. It also depends on the api-level & the OEM's own implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people in the comments have said, it is a system dialog and you cannot change it. If you want to help users find your app's settings you can try [sending them there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-can-i-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-andr).

Also note that according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial)

> Starting in Android 11 (API level 30), if the user taps Deny for a specific permission more than once during your app's lifetime of installation on a device, the user doesn't see the system permissions dialog if your app requests that permission again. The user's action implies "don't ask again."

So you have to deal with permanent denials even if there isn't a dedicated button.