# How to link a user to the settings page to change permission to know location?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, browser, frontend

A user has denied my app permission to know their location via GPS. They did this by accident. How the app needs to link them to the settings page where they can change the permission.

How to make this link? Does it depend on browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-can-i-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-andr

Answer (score 1):

This intent will open the Settings page and the user can change the settings he/she denied by mistake

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(appDetails.packageName,"com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.ManagePermissionsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How about the desktop chrome browser?